# Get unique data from one column based on another

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset in which there are states and cities, now a state has multiple cities and I want to group them by state and convert the output into JSON

dataframe

```
    City     State
0   A        foo
1   B        bar
2   D        foo
3   C        moo
4   E        foo
5   F        bar
```

I am doing this:

```
df = data[["City","State"]]
df.groupby("State")
```

But I get the following

```
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x00000265BC3422C8>
```

JSON:

```
{ 'foo':[A,D,E],
  'bar':[B,F],
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: How looks final `json` from sample data?

Comment: @jezrael It should look like a state and all it's respective cities

Comment: hmmm, I think format.

Comment: Do you think `df.groupby('State')['City'].apply(list).to_json()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert values to sets and then to lists for remove duplicates and then to `json`:

```
j = df.groupby('State')['City'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x))).to_json()
print (j)
{"bar":["B","F"],"foo":["A","E","D"],"moo":["C"]}
```

Or remove duplciates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and then aggregate `list`s:

```
j = df.drop_duplicates(['State','City']).groupby('State')['City'].apply(list).to_json()
```

Comment: I tried this and it gives all the cities even if they are being repeated, can we apply unique here. The output looks like this `{ 'foo':[A,A,,A,A,E...],
  'bar':[B,B,B,F,F,F,F,F,F,F],...}'